kdb/q Left join does not aggregate all info, is there a better way to group data?
I have two tables:
date_table:
date: original date,
id: identifier,
Plus1: date + 1,
Plus2: date + 2,
Neg1: Date - 1,
Neg2: Date - 2



Date
ID
Plus1
Plus2
Neg1
Neg2




1/1/24
1A
1/2/24
1/3/24
12/31/23
12/30/23


1/5/24
2B
1/6/24
1/7/24
1/4/24
1/3/24



date_table: ([] Date: 2024.01.01 2024.01.05; ID: `1A`2B; Plus1: 2024.01.02 2024.01.06; Plus2: 2024.01.03 2024.01.07; Neg1: 2023.12.31 2024.01.04; Neg2: 2023.12.30 2024.01.03)

data:



Date
ID
Name
Place




1/1/24
1A
Ann
SF


12/31/23
1A
Sue
Seattle


12/20/23
1A
Ian
NY


1/5/24
2B
Bob
LA


1/7/24
2B
Ian
Fort Worth


1/1/24
1A
XYZ
Chicago



data: ([] Date: 2024.01.01 2023.12.31 2023.12.20 2024.01.05 2024.01.07 2024.01.01; ID: `1A`1A`1A`2B`2B`1A; Name: `Ann`Sue`Ian`Bob`Ian`XYZ; Place: `SF`Seattle`NY`LA`FortWorth`Chicago)

What I want to get is the list of unique Names and Places for each data_table within the Date range and matching ID.
From the two tables above, I would like the following:



Date
ID
Name
Place




1/1/24
1A
Ann
SF


12/31/23
1A
Sue
Seattle


1/5/24
2B
Bob
LA


1/7/24
2B
Ian
FortWorth


1/1/24
1A
XYZ
Chicago



Note that the 12/20/23-Ian row from the data table is left out because the date is not within the original date +/- 2 days range.
I was thinking of doing something like date_table lj `Date`ID xkey select Date, ID, Name, Place from data;, however, this kind of left join doesn't take into account the + and - 2 days around the Date column. It also doesn't take into account the multiple Name/Place combinations, such as on 1/1/24 ID 1A has two rows that match (Ann from SF and XYZ from Chicago).
This is what the left join outputs:



Date
ID
Plus1
Plus2
Neg1
Neg2
Name
Place




2024.01.01
1A
2024.01.02
2024.01.03
2023.12.31
2023.12.30
Ann
SF


2024.01.05
2B
2024.01.06
2024.01.07
2024.01.04
2024.01.03
Bob
LA



One thing I can think of is doing 5 different left joins, one for each Date and then aggregate, however I think there may be a better way to get this output, especially because the left join does not aggregate all Name/Place data.
I was thinking of using left joins because there is a lot of data, and going row by row will be extremely slow. Appreciate any ideas as I'm not sure the direction I'm going is correct.
Let me know if you need me to clarify.

One method you could use that doesn't require lj:
q)raze{?[data;((=;`ID;enlist x);(within;`Date;y,z));0b;()]}.'flip date_table`ID`Neg2`Plus2
Date       ID Name Place
----------------------------
2024.01.01 1A Ann  SF
2023.12.31 1A Sue  Seattle
2024.01.01 1A XYZ  Chicago
2024.01.05 2B Bob  LA
2024.01.07 2B Ian  FortWorth

Here I'm using the relevant entries from data_table as arguments to a function.
q)date_table`ID`Neg2`Plus2
1A         2B
2023.12.30 2024.01.03
2024.01.03 2024.01.07

The function is a functional select that selects entries for an ID within its allowed range (x is the ID, y is the start of range and z is the end).
{?[data;((=;`ID;enlist x);(within;`Date;y,z));0b;()]}

The function is run for each ID and range, and the results are combined together with raze.

Thank you very much for your detailed answer, it really helps me to understand the breakdown of the code in the raze function. I would give you an upvote but it looks like I don't have enough reputation yet

If your date_table is static this looks like a good use-case for a foreign key relationship.
q)keyed_date_table:`ID xkey date_table
q)linked_data:update ID:`keyed_date_table$ID from data
q)select from linked_data where Date within'(ID.Neg2,'ID.Plus2)
Date       ID Name Place
----------------------------
2024.01.01 1A Ann  SF
2023.12.31 1A Sue  Seattle
2024.01.05 2B Bob  LA
2024.01.07 2B Ian  FortWorth
2024.01.01 1A XYZ  Chicago

Above is effectively the equivalent of doing:
q)select from data where Date within'(exec raze(Neg2;Plus2)by ID from date_table)[ID]
Date       ID Name Place
----------------------------
2024.01.01 1A Ann  SF
2023.12.31 1A Sue  Seattle
2024.01.05 2B Bob  LA
2024.01.07 2B Ian  FortWorth
2024.01.01 1A XYZ  Chicago


Thanks for providing a different solution, I was trying this but got a cast error on the '$ID' part of my code, do you know why this might be the case?

I few things to check: (1) is your date_table keyed on ID? (2) is the ID in date_table of the exact same datatype as the ID in data table? Check for enumerations if its a symbol column (3) are all of the IDs in data table also in the IDs in the date_table? If the answer to any of these is false then that's your issue

For 1 and 2, yes they are, however for #3 it is the case that the data table has more IDs than in the date_table. I just need those IDs from the date_table to search in the data table

Ok, then the foreign key setup won't work unless you put all the missing IDs in the date_table with infinite or null date and thus have them included/excluded in a neg2/plus2 filter
